# What is the cycle structure of a graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I have a vague imagination of what the *cycle structure* of a graph might be - something taking into account the numbers, lengths, Hamiltonianicities, Eulerianicities and whatsoever of cycles of a graph and their quantified interweavings - and there are of course papers and books mentioning the cycle structure of graphs - see [Quo vadis, graph theory?](http://books.google.com/books?id=LmUZVmhrvU8C&pg=PA145&dq=%22cycle+structure%22&hl=en&ei=7DyZTKrSGczAswajseyLDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22cycle%20structure%22&f=false), for example - but I cannot find a tangible definition to start with.

> **Question**: What might be a sensible definition of "cycle structure"?

Comment: This is very much *not a real question* as it stands... You surely agree?

Comment: On the one hand I agree; on the other, I have an answer (written below).

Comment: If you ask *me*: of course it is a real question! Should I re-formulate it? It is a matter of fact that the term "cycle structure" is in use, and I am looking for a definition. Maybe I am mislead and it does not make sense to look for such a definition?

Comment: Hans, the text you wrote does not ask anything. *What do you want to know?*

Comment: I edited the text, now there is a question. Sorry for that.

Comment: Hans: one might point out that finding _good_ structures that capture this information (aside from the ones mentioned below) is in some sense a meta-goal in algebraic graph theory.

Answer (score 11):

This is a vague question, but here is an attempt at an answer. Let $G$ be a graph, let $E$ be the set of edges of $G$, and let $C \subset 2^E$ be the set of cycles of $G$. Then knowing $C$ is equivalent to the [matroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroid#Matroids_from_graph_theory) of $G$. Two graphs produce the same matroid if and only if they are related by a sequence of the following moves:

(1) Taking two connected components and gluing them along a single vertex, or undoing the above.

(2) If $G$ has two vertices $u$ and $v$ so that $G \setminus \{ u,v \}$ is disconnected, cutting along those vertices and regluing some of the pieces back with $u$ and $v$ switched.

In particular, if a graph is $3$-connected, then it is determined by its matroid.

So one answer could be "The cycle structure of a graph is its matroid" and, as the above shows, this contains almost as much information as the graph.

Comment: I'll just comment that I agree that this is what cycle structure of a graph means.  Also, the theorem that David mentions was first proven by Whitney.

Comment: This sounds very promising. But if this was a real answer, why isn't my question a real question? 

Answer (score 4):

Another possible answer is the [cycle space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_space) of a graph, which is a vector space and so supports the application of many tools from linear algebra.

Comment: Another promising answer! So the "cycle structure" of a graph might be the structure of its cycle space? Why not!

Comment: Yes, and from the cycle space we can still recover some properties of a graph.  For example, MacClane's Theorem says that a graph is planar if and only if its cycle space has a 2-basis (a basis such that every edge is contained in at most 2 basis vectors).  

Comment: @Tony: You commented and agreed with both of the answers. Is it obvious that they mean essentially the same?

Comment: I suppose that I have a split personality.  They don't actually mean the same thing.  It is a matter of perspective. As an object, the cycle space is technically larger than the cycle matroid since the former contains all Eulerian subgraphs, while the later only contains cycles (circuits).  Of course, we can represent the cycle space compactly by just listing the fundamental cycles of the graph.  So in another sense the cycle space is smaller than the cycle matroid.  

Comment: If the cycle space is larger than the cycle matroid when seen as an OBJECT, seen as WHAT it is smaller than the cycle matroid? (Just want to get the proper context.)

Comment: The cycle space is bigger than the cycle matroid if we view both of them as just sets. But since the linear algebraist is allowed to take linear combinations (in this case symmetric differences), he only needs to list a basis for the cycle space in order to represent it. It turns out that he only has to list |E(G)|-|V(G)|+1 cycles. On the other hand the matroid theorist has to list all the cycles, since he is viewing the set of cycles as a matroid

Comment: I just wanted to mention as an aside that, as far as I know, it is an open problem to find a polynomial-time algorithm to construct a minimum weight integral cycle basis in a directed graph. Such "best bases" have application to event scheduling, so they are of considerable interest.

Comment: Also note that the cycle basis of a graph as defined above is a special case of the 1st homology group of a simplicial complex